# How to add custom attributes to powerpoint presentation slide using apple script?

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, powerpoint

I want to add  Two attributes/parameters to each slide in my presentation (slideId and hash code) using apple script. I have done lots of research for doing this, but I didn't get any single solution for this scenario .

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @AkshayKhetrapal: I am very new to apple script and in general I got the solution like , I need to rename the pptx file with extension zip and extract the Content_Type file xml and adding attributes to xml file.

Comment: @AkshayKhetrapal : Do you know how to add custom attributes to slides in presentation using apple script ?

Comment: Have you tried using `set attributeName to value`

Comment: @AkshayKhetrapal : I have tried with attributeName, but its showing "missing value".If possible, Can you please give me the exact code to set the attribute to pptx. It will be helpful

Comment: Each slide in a presentation already has a unique SlideID property.  Is there some reason for adding another?  In any case, consider using tags. Each presentation, slide and shape can have a collection of tags, essentially named string values. In VBA, you'd do Slide.Tags.Add "SomeName", "SomeValue"